# Python 3.8.5 WON'T assign a specific string value as a dictionary key

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/analytical_writing/issue/pool to grab specific paragraphs and arrange them into pairs. The following code does the job until a specific paragraph, where i=43, that just won't be added by `dict[key]=""` and consequently `IndexError: list index out of range` raises. The paragraph is namely:

> Universities should require every student to take a variety of courses outside the student's field of study.

I tried to find a different pattern around it and failed. What am I getting wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
with open("D:\\Users\\assem\\Documents\\Academia\\GRE\\Introduction to the GRE Issue Task (For Test Takers).html") as fp:
    soup=BeautifulSoup(fp)
Dict={}
i=0
while soup.p:
    x=soup.p.get_text()
    if not 'Write a response' in x:
        try:
            if Dict[y]=="":
                Dict[y+x]=Dict.pop(y)
            else:
                Dict[x]=""
        except:
            Dict[x]=""
        y=list(Dict.keys())[i]
    else:
        Dict[y]=x
        i=i+1
    soup.p.decompose()
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Dict)
print(df)
```

Comment: Why are you using a bare `except`? If you want to know what is wrong with your code, that is the *worst* thing you can do. (Hint: what is the value of `y` inside the try-block?)

Comment: You wouldn't have this problem with @AKX 's answer but you should generally keep in mind that `dict().keys()` can be indeterministic regarding the order or elements since 'normal' dictionaries themselves are that way

Comment: @r0w Dictionaries _happen_ to retain insertion order since Python 3.7 though.

Comment: Turned out the key was duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @AKX good to know, I must have missed that somehow, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering each question/answer pair is separated by a divider element, you will probably have a better time walking each of those pairs instead of consuming paragraphs out of the document.

```
import bs4

with open("pool.htm") as fp:
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(fp, features="html.parser")

for divider_node in soup.find_all("div", class_="divider-50"):
    node = divider_node.next_sibling
    questions = []
    answers = []
    while node:
        if isinstance(node, bs4.Tag):
            cls = node.attrs.get("class")
            if cls == ["divider-50"]:
                # Found the divider, stop
                break
            elif node.name == "p":
                questions.append(node.get_text().strip())
            elif cls == ["indented"]:
                answers.append(node.get_text().strip())
        node = node.next_sibling
    print({"q": questions, "a": answers})
```

prints out e.g.

```
{'q': ['To understand the most important characteristics of a society, one must study its major cities.'], 'a': ['Write a response in which you discuss the extent to which you agree or disagree with the statement and explain your reasoning for the position you take. In developing and supporting your position, you should consider ways in which the statement might or might not hold true and explain how these considerations shape your position.']}
{'q': ['Educational institutions have a responsibility to dissuade students from pursuing fields of study in which they are unlikely to succeed.'], 'a': ['Write a response in which you discuss the extent to which you agree or disagree with the claim. In developing and supporting your position, be sure to address the most compelling reasons and/or examples that could be used to challenge your position.']}
{'q': ['Scandals are useful because they focus our attention on problems in ways that no speaker or reformer ever could.'], 'a': ['Write a response in which you discuss the extent to which you agree or disagree with the claim. In developing and supporting your position, be sure to address the most compelling reasons and/or examples that could be used to challenge your position.']}
{'q': ['Claim: Governments must ensure that their major cities receive the financial support they need in order to thrive.', "Reason: It is primarily in cities that a nation's cultural traditions are preserved and generated."], 'a': ['Write a response in which you discuss the extent to which you agree or disagree with the claim and the reason on which that claim is based.']}
```

Comment: I first thought about utilizing dividers to tackle it but couldnt get around the syntax properly. This worked and was way more efficient, thanks!